# Can't get the updated value in the context provider

Tags: reactjs

I have a context provider in which I pass a function that is used in another component which uses the context. Basically when the new value is set, I have it on the body of the provider but not in the function inside the body. Here is the example:

```
const ProviderContainer = (props) => {
    /* this is passed to the function which uses the context */
    const [value, setValue] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

    /* when the function that uses the context calls the setValue, the value gets updated */
    console.log(value) // { x: 5, y: 5 }

    const setPosition = () => {
        /* and in this case, the value of x and y is still 0 */
        console.log(value);
    };

    return (
        <Provider value=({ setValue }) />
    );
};

const ConsumerFunction = () => {
    const context = useContext();

    // setting the value which goes to the provider correctly
    context.setValue({ x: 5, y: 5 });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the `setPosition` function.

Here I execute it on *Log the coordinates* button click:

```js
const { useState, useContext } = React;

const Context = React.createContext();

function App() {
  return <ProviderContainer />;
}

function ProviderContainer() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  console.log(value);

  const setPosition = () => {
    console.log('Coordinates:', value);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={setValue}>
      <Consumer />
      <button onClick={setPosition}>Log the coordinates</button>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

function Consumer() {
  const setValue = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Select coordinates: </span>
      <button onClick={() => setValue({ x: 1, y: 1 })}>x: 1, y: 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue({ x: 2, y: 2 })}>x: 2, y: 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

However, even when using the Context is possible here, you can use easier techniques e.g.: pass `setValue` as props. You can read more about the React's team opinion on using Context in documentation: [Context - Before You Use Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) .